# Proving that a module homomorphism is an isomorphism if and only if the induced map between the localizations is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, localization

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of a ring $R$. Let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules, and let $f:M \rightarrow N$ be a module homomorphism. Let $f_P: M_P \rightarrow N_P$ be defined by $f_P \left(\frac{m}{s} \right) = \frac{f(m)}{s}$. I want to show that $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f_P$ is an isomorphism, for all $P$. I proved the forward direction, but am stuck going the other way. When I try setting $f(m) = 0$, I end up with $\frac{0}{1} = \frac{f(m)}{1}$ and $sm = 0$ for some $s \in R \setminus P$, but since I'm not assuming $M$ is torsion free, this doesn't give me injectivity. My other idea was to set up the diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> M @>>>  M_P @>>> M_P / M @>>> 0 \\
@VVV & @VfVV  @Vf_PVV & @VVV & @VVV\\
0 @>>> N @>>> N_P @>>> N_P / N @>>> 0
\end{CD}

and appeal to the five lemma, but I'm not convinced the obvious maps in the rows are exact; requiring the natural isomorphisms $M \rightarrow M_P$ and $N \rightarrow N_P$ to be injective seems equivalent to requiring $M$ to be torsion free.

Comment: Are you assuming this for only one prime $P$? That is not enough. You need to assume this for all primes and then from what you wrote, this should be obvious.

Comment: @Mohan What exactly are you referring to? I'm not sure where I assumed anything about $P$. I'm trying to prove this statement for arbitrary rings, prime ideals, and modules.

Comment: $f:M\to N$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f_P:M_P\to N_P$  is an isomorphism for ALL prime ideals $P$ and not just one prime ideal.

Comment: The final word in the title should be *isomorphism*. Just don't use `&` in a `CD` environment (look at the edit I made).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proposition as you stated is **false**. When discussing local properties, you always need **all** prime ideals. Assuming that is what you meant, let's see how we can deduce this then.

The result is an easy consequence that localization is an exact functor. Let $f: A \to B$, $g: B \to C$ such that there is an exact sequence

$$A \to B \to C$$

Claim that $S^{-1} A \to S^{-1} B \to S^{-1} C$ is exact. It's clear that $\text{im } S^{-1} f \subseteq \ker S^{-1} g$. So now start with $b/s$ in the kernel. Then $g(b)/s = 0$ so there is a an $s \in S$ such that $sg(b) =g(sb) = 0$ in $C$, i.e. $sb \in \ker g$ which is the image of $f$.

Now an isomorphism fits into an exact sequence by saying $M \cong N$ if and only if $0 \to M \to N \to 0$ is exact. Thus if $M \cong N$ then apply the functor $S^{-1}$, where $S = R - p$.

Conversely, suppose $M_p \cong N_p$. Show that $M \to N$ is both injective and surjective separately. You can do this by considering the exact sequences

$$0 \to K \to M \to N$$ and $$M \to N \to C \to 0$$

where $K$ and $C$ are the kernel and cokernel respectively.

Apply the localization functor and use the fact that for an $R$-module $T$, $T = 0 \Leftrightarrow T_p = 0$ for all prime ideals $p$.

Comment: I have added that. Thank you!